# How do I use pseudo class css to list item?

Tags: html, css, navigation, nav, pseudo-class

I wanted to color the "Home" button from the navigation list to make it blue.

I've used the code below but it doesn't work. I can't find it actually where's the problem?

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.menu ul {
  display: flex;
}

.menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 15px 25px;
}

.menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: green;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.menu ul li:first-child {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">
      <h2><a href="http://">Bangladesh</a></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: You have set a color (green) using a selector which is more precise than the first-child selection. Change the first-child selection to .menu ul li:first-child a {color: blue;}

Answer (score 0):

You set the color on the "a" element to green

With the pseudo class you set the li element to blue but the inner a element overwrites it with green

If you make it

".menu ul li:first-child a"

it works

```css
nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.menu ul {
    display: flex;
}

.menu ul li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 15px 25px;
}

.menu ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: green;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.menu ul li:first-child a {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <nav>
        <div class="logo">
            <h2><a href="http://">Bangladesh</a></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Patrick. I'm really grateful to you.